# garbage characters while inserting string to a linked list in c

Tags: c, string, linked-list, insert, character

So, what Im trying to achieve with this, is to create a linked list with three strings as data. The output shows the expected strings, but adds some garbage symbols, f.ex.: expected "string pierwszy", got : "string pierwszyn~rŚÝ".

I also tried to print out the strlen(tmp->word) and I got 3. I dont get it, i thought it would be 1. I dont get, why is it like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element element;

struct element{
    char * word;
    element * next;
};

element * head = NULL;

void addWord(char * new_word){
    printf("new_word: %s\n\n\n", new_word);

    element *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(element));

    element *current = head;

    tmp->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(new_word)+1);
    strncpy(tmp->word, new_word, strlen(new_word));
    tmp->word[strlen(new_word)] = "\0";

    tmp->next = current;
    head = tmp;

}
void free_list(element * node){
    if(node != NULL){
        free_list(node->next);
        free(node->word);
        free(node);
    }
}
void print_list(element * node){
    element * tmp = node;
    while(tmp != NULL){
        printf("word: %s\n", tmp->word);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char * name1 = "string pierwszy";
    char * name2 = "drugi";
    char * name3 = "333trzeci";

    addWord(name1);
    addWord(name2);
    addWord(name3);
    print_list(head);

    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man strncpy`: *[...]The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of  src  are
       copied.   Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.[...]*

Comment: The following code `tmp->word[strlen(new_word)] = "\0";` doesn't compile. replace the `"\0";` (a string) by `'\0'` (a null-terminator character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
tmp->word[strlen(new_word)] = "\0";
```

There is a difference between `"\0"` and `'\0'`. `'\0'` is correct in this situation, since it's simply a null character. `"\0"` is a string containing a null character, so it's exactly the same thing as
`{'\0', '\0'}` (one null character for the one you entered and one which is added automatically).

Since arrays in C are treated as pointers for some purposes, the code that you wrote creates an array of two null characters in the memory, takes the address of the first element, converts it to a `char` using the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) and stores it in the string. So what you did is basically equivalent to doing this:

```
char someString[2];
someString[0] = '\0';
someString[1] = '\0';
tmp->word[strlen(new_word)] = (char)&(someString[0]);
```

Since the string doesn't have any terminated null character because of this, it doesn't know where the string ends so it continues a couple of characters giving you the characters that just happened to be in the memory.

So the first "garbage" character as you say is the ASCII equivalent of the address of some string, and the other ones are what happened to be in the memory right there and right then.

The correct code is of course the following:

```
tmp->word[strlen(new_word)] = '\0';
```